# A word for a person concerned with spelling

Tags: single-word-requests

What do we call a person who is very much concerned with correct spelling of a word but especially with name.

> That person is ......?

Comment: meticulous, pedantic, a school teacher.

Comment: its not about all english word. its about when someone spell wrong in common words.

Comment: So are you asking for a word for a person who spells common words badly, or for a person who is annoyed by such common misspellings?

Comment: A person can't be a sentiment. I'd edit this question to fix the gross grammar errors, except I can't make heads or tails of it. (For one thing, I think "sentiment" might be a false friend with a word in your native language, or something: you're using it so incorrectly that it's apparent you have no idea what it means.)

Comment: @Mitch I want word for both you mentioned.

Comment: @Marthaª : Thanks for correcting my sentence. I am sorry but i tried my best to shape up the question.

Comment: The person who makes the spelling mistakes is 'uneducated' or 'spells badly' or is a 'bad speller'. There is little distinction between misspelling big words or small words. If you use 'there' for 'their' or 'enthimeme' for 'enthymeme', they're both gone by 'bad spellers'.

Comment: The person who is annoyed by this is either 'a normal person' or, if  annoyed by the rare misspelling, the items in my first comment.

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández diEcho may have meant "bothered" or "annoyed" rather than "disturbed", but I did not want to alter the question's stated intent too much in my edit. Keep in mind that if something "disturbs" you, it may "inconvenience" you, not make you mentally unstable. diEcho, did Mitch's suggestions answer your question? I don't think we need to look at this as a psychological disorder. Look up the definitions of "disturb", "bother" and "annoy" and see if these apply to the person's experience.

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández: I think it would be perverse to interpret OP's "disturbed" as having clinical implications. I won't go so far as to say I'm disturbed by your presumption, but I'll certainly say it's uncalled-for.

Comment: This question could be improved by clarifying how the word would be used. As it is, the question is overly broad and therefore liable to be closed "not really a question". Do you wish to describe the person but also express your opinion (positive or negative) about such a person? Or do you want a purely factual description? Also, why should this term cover only a concern about *common* words?

Comment: This is a fine question. I don't understand the downvotes. +1

Comment: a perfectionist, stickler, purist, formalist, precisionist; obsessive

Comment: A *spell wart*, informally at least. A la *worry wart*.

Comment: __Warning__, may be offensive. But it is very common: a *grammar nazi*. Wait, it's about spelling, not grammar, no? Well, that's basically right: but for that you have to know, that some English native speakers telling about somebody "who can't spell properly" will leave it open to the person they speak to whether they only mean "bad spelling" or also "bad grammar" additionally to that.

Comment: ...is likely someone who has few friends.

Comment: The current example sentence "That person is..." doesn't do much to say what type of word you want. Noun or adjective? Positive or negative?

Comment: There really should be a statute of limitations on attempts to close longtime questions on this site. This one has been on EL&U longer than I have. I'm voting to Leave Open.

Comment: [Here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192177/word-for-someone-who-always-corrects-misspellings) is a similar question. My vote goes to "spelling nazi".

Answer (score 8):

There are more general terms, such as [pedant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pedant) *- one who pays undue attention to ... formal rules*, but I'm pretty sure there isn't a specific word for the type of person OP describes.

The problem is it's unlikely anyone would have that particular personality quirk in isolation. Anyone who's a *"stickler for orthographic correctness"* in OP's sense is likely care as much about, say, punctuation as they are about spelling. And they'd probably be more fussy than average about correct verb tenses, and wouldn't like people writing in green ink, ball-point pen, etc.,

Noting that [some people have used](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=malorthography&oq=malorthography&gs_l=hp.3..0i13i30l3.938212.945013.1.945460.7.7.0.0.0.0.251.663.6j0j1.7.0...0.0...1c.1.YQauT5ulXQo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=5c5561eb61e4ee05&biw=1379&bih=886) the relatively transparent coinage [malorthography](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Fresh%20Butter%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=malorthography&hl=en&tbm=bks&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=p_pMUJ7OCMTY0QWRjoG4Ag&ved=0CCMQpwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3b003db65f44374e&biw=1379&bih=886), OP might wish to consider my neologism

> [malorthographobe](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Fresh%20Butter%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=malorthographobe&oq=malorthographobe&gs_l=serp.3...94461.96213.1.96693.4.4.0.0.0.0.79.238.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.hJ01_kUMn-A&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3b003db65f44374e&biw=1379&bih=886) *- one who intensely dislikes incorrect orthography (specifically, **misspellings**)*.

Comment: Shouldn't it be malorthographophobe?

Comment: @David Wallace: Technically speaking, you're right. But since it's *my* neologism, I shall propose my own version. By re-using the "ph" from "graph" and "phobe" I'm saving the world's dwindling ink reserves (if it takes off and gets printed in lots of dead-tree publications! :)

Comment: Would ***any*** of those 4 downvoters care to justify themselves? ELU has a long history of proposing extended phrases and neologisms if no existing single word meets some request.

Comment: @Xavier Vidal Hernández: Okay, thanks (you posted while I was making the previous comment). I disagree that justication here, obviously. You will also note that I did provide evidence that some people have used the term *malorthography*, and I respectfully suggest I do *not* need to cite sources for the *-phobe* suffix. David Wallace's demurral being duly noted and discounted, I maintain that my answer is valid in this context.

Comment: Yeah, jeez, read the FAQ! You're never going to get to 50k reputation with answers like this! Also, I'm really excited! (mocking aside, +1 for pedant)

Comment: @Cameron: I freely admitted *"pedant"* is more general than OP's target. I know I could have proposed *"stickler for spelling"* for a phrasal alternative, but I felt *"...orthographic correctness"* was a better lead-in to my neologism. Which doesn't seem to have got off to a flying start, I must admit (David's longer version currently has 1 upvote, mine has a net -2 downvotes! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: About your "free admission" – even if one doesn't think _pendant_ is a perfect choice, I've always found it rather distasteful to downvote a suggested word, particularly when it's first up on the board, where it can get the discussion rolling, and springboard other thinking. So long as the word isn't outright misinformation – which _pendant_ clearly isn't – I would avoid downvoting simply because a word doesn't fit as perfectly as Cinderella's slipper.

Comment: @J.R. "Pedant".

Comment: @J.R.: Well, apparently I'm climbing out of the depths here, having moved from -4 to + 1. But OP has really set the cat among the pigeons, having climbed from -8 to +3. I think we just have a lot of "vote-close-happy" users in tonight (or your "this morning", or whatever! :)

Comment: @ΜετάEd: Yes, _pedant_, of course. (Maybe _that's_ why FF's answer was downvoted – maybe someone else misread, just as I mistyped! After all, _pendant_ is NOT a very apt word). P.S. It's rather ironic that I made that gaffe on a question about misspelling...

Comment: What??  You can't even spell your neologisms right???

Answer (score 1):

**Orthography** is the part of language study concerned with letters and spelling.

Maybe an orthographist?  :)

http://www.dictionary.com/wordoftheday/2016/07/05/orthography

Edit: Here is a link to a definition of it: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/orthographist

Comment: Hello, Ben. Welcome to English Language and Usage. The answer to the question is in the first comment above and you need to provide a definitive answer with reference and actual usage examples. The word *orthographist* doesn't seem to exist. Please visit our help center and read the guidelines. We don't encourage posting an answer without any reference.

Comment: +1 This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content, but it's a good start. 
A good answer is comprehensive and contains evidence showing why it is correct. For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good answer, see [answer]. I agree an *orthographist* might be a specialist in writing words using “proper” or accepted spelling. If you are going to coin a word, be careful to explain that the person using it might need to give a definition in order to be understood. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Sheesh, tough crowd.  I'll be more careful the next time I try to help.

Comment: @MετάEd This answer was flagged by myself. Have you ever seen the word "orthographist" used in the OP's context?

Comment: @Rathony As I said, I think Ben is on the right track. A coined term is sometimes a good answer. This one seems better than *malorthographobe*. See the recent question at Meta: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/8077/14073

Comment: @MετάEd Well, I don't object to suggesting a coined word, but my question is will it make sense?

Comment: @Rathony Also as I said, it will provided the person using it is willing to define it. It might even catch on.

Comment: @MετάEd I just wonder how this question has not been closed for almost 4 years. No context, no example sentence. Orthographer, orthographist both might work. But the problem is based on the OP's question, I think the Mitch's comment is the only answer. Is there any word for a person who is concerned about spelling a name correctly? ELU's problem. We should close all the SWR questions without any example sentence or context.

Comment: @MετάEd I will close-vote it tomorrow.

Comment: @Rathony Can we discuss this in [chat]?