# Word for someone who always corrects misspellings

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Is there a specific word for the type of person who always corrects misspellings? Something exact, not something like perfectionist, grammar nazi or anal.

Something that describes the person, like the word ultracrepidarian does for a person who gives advice outside their knowledge.

Comment: Do you want to have a word with some positive tone or negative? Or even neutral?

Comment: @Neeku, neutral is fine... just describing the person who has the impulse to always correct misspellings.

Comment: If it's an actual compulsion then simply "compulsive speller" would work since it spells out the motivation.

Comment: You mean like- a [born] proofreader/copy editor/English teacher?

Comment: Answer is already chosen but I still believe that the most suitable answer is "spelling nazi". Just mentioning here so people can see.

Comment: @ermanen and by extension "Grammar Nazi", however that is misused quite often by people who just like the sound of the phrase.

Comment: It's because of these people that I always purposely splel "splel" "splel", and then pretend it's a typo if called out on it

Comment: "mother" comes to mind!

Comment: @ermanen: although if the correcter of misspellings does so in the hope of being helpful and is courteous about it, then that's rather like calling someone a "coffee nazi" because they always offer you a coffee when you visit their home. Is there a word for the type of person who refers to all behaviour they dislike as nazism? A "nazi nazi"? ;-)

Comment: I just call them "idiots"... nothing more seems to fit in.

Comment: @ermanen Nazi is a noun and also a name. In German ALL nouns are capitalised. Thus if you want to be correct you should spell it spelling Nazi (I won’t get into the complete German as that doesn’t matter). Just so you know… and yes obviously the irony is intended though having a love for German I still would have pointed it out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't believe there's an exact word for "*someone who corrects others' spelling errors*", but there is one for a person who is *meticulous in spelling*, generally:

> [***orthographer***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orthographer) (*lit.* "[right writer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=orthography&allowed_in_frame=0)"): One versed in orthography; one who spells words correctly, according to approved usage.

If there is a single word which indicates (as @ermanen puts it) a "*spelling Nazi*", it will almost certainly be derived from "*orthography*" or "*orthographer*"; you might consider deriving one yourself, or popularizing a new sense for an existing word, such as:

- "***orthographizer***", derived from "[*orthographize*](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/cent2jpgframes.php?volno=05&page=4162)" meaning "*to write or spell correctly*", which (I think) nicely emphasizes the *transitive* nature of his compulsion (i.e. not only ensuring his spelling is perfect, but *yours*, too), or
- "***orthographist***", has the advantage of possessing that dogmatic little tail, [*-ism*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ism#Suffix), but is currently only used to describe a *specialist* in orthography, or "*one who studies orthography*".  So you can either popularize a new sense for it, or extend it a bit to underscore the adherence to received protocols (an "***orthodoxic orthographist***"? an "***observant othographer***"? the possibilities are endless).

---

***EDIT***: You might also consider ***unpopular*** :)
[image: Obsessive compulsive grammar disorder]

Comment: +1 Or maybe *orthographic pedant*?

Comment: Corrigitis cannot be cured by a physician.

Comment: Unpopular is the wrong word here. Being unpopular is merely a (possible) side-effect of correcting people.

Comment: Yes, @Aeron, that was the joke.

Comment: Lol. Sorry about that @Dan, I seem to have a hard time telling the difference between jokes and non jokes in writing lately.

Comment: Surely to "over-exaggerate" means "to exaggerate more than is warranted by the situation", and therefore is not redundant (although it probably isn't what the doctor means, I think he does mean to say that the patient is exaggerating). Just saying, the best way to deal with these people is to play their game until you're bored and then leave :-)

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps *[spellchecker](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/spellchecker)*? (Whether we like it or not.) [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

[Who says computing terms can't be applied to people, as in *Thank you, Mr. Spellchecker. Maybe I meant to write* check *instead of* cheque.]

And as @DanBron points out, our slightly stuffier crowd might deem him or her *autocorrector*.

Comment: Hee hee. I like that. +1.

Comment: Oh, please, oh *please*, add [***autocorrector***](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com/) to your answer.

Comment: @DanBron You just did. I'll punch it in since comments don't last forever (and my answer is destined for immortality!).

Comment: I only regret that I have but +1 to give for this answer :(

Comment: @DanBron Please note that I voted for the acknowledged righter answer even before I posted.

Comment: I really enjoyed this answer, and I hope "spellchecker" or "autocorrector" takes off as a moniker we can apply to pedantic spellers (and I doubt,orthographizist or whatever will, whether "righter" or not. Except when these people are talking about themselves, of course ;).

Answer (score 10):

This is one behavior commonly associated with a *[pedant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedant)* is, per Merriam-Webster:

> ped·ant noun \ˈpe-dənt\
>   : a person who annoys other people by correcting small errors and giving too much attention to minor details

Answer (score 6):

There is also ***spelling nazi*** as a neologism which is derived from *grammar nazi*.

[Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=spelling%20nazi) and [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpellingNazi) have entries for spelling nazi and there are some usages in [Google Books](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=RW7zU-yfJIqN8Qf1goGADg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22spelling%20nazi%22&safe=off&start=110&tbm=bks).

> - a person who freaks out when a little spelling mistake has occured or has be a constant little a**hole about it.
> - people that care more about the spelling of words and correcting them then what the words mean...
>
> [[urbandictionary]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=spelling%20nazi)

**Note:** There isn't a single word that conveys this idea. *Spelling nazi* would be the most common colloquial phrase and it is self-explanatory.

[image] 
<sup>Source: http://www.documentingreality.com</sup>

**Note:** "Grammar nazi" is a misnomer that covers all language mistakes which includes spelling. So that might be why "spelling nazi" is derived. Some sources mention as a subtype of grammar nazi.

Comment: Is it ironic that the spelling nazi definition uses *then* instead of *than*?

Comment: No: a *spelling nazi* cannot be a specific type of *grammar nazi*, because **spelling has nothing *whatsobloodyever* do to with grammar!**

Comment: Though, it is not the same discussion as the difference between grammar and spelling. "Grammar nazi" is a misnomer that covers all language mistakes which includes spelling. So that might be why "spelling nazi" is derived. Some sources mention as a subtype of grammar nazi.